# Strange constraints behaviour on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode6, autolayout, constraints

I try to do one of the simples things ever and get a strange result.

I have a UIViewController with one UIImageView inside

[image: Views]

I set the constraints like follow

[image: constraints]

And I get the following result

[image]

My questions are

1. Why I get a padding on the left and right side? To remove that padding I have to use a constrains from -20 instead of -16 but then is the frame x - 4.
2. Why Is the Vertical space to superview (top space) automatically -20

Does someone has this behaviour before and now how to solve it?

https://github.com/eikebartels/iPadTest
https://github.com/eikebartels/iPadTest.git

Thanks in advance,

Eike

Comment: In iOS 8, views have margins. Look closely at your constraints. Are they tied to the _margins_ of the superview, or to the superview itself?

Comment: actually to the superview itself.. but the superview creates a margin after.

Comment: I don't know what you did in response to Matt's answer, but I downloaded you github project, and looked at your constraints. If you double click on one (either the trailing or leading constraint), you will see that it says Margin next to one of the items. If you uncheck the "Relative to Margin" box, and set the constant to 0, you no longer see the red background. You should accept Matt's answer, it is the correct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you've connected your constraints to the superview's *margins*. If you want to reach the edge of the superview you need to connect to the superview *itself* (with a constant of zero).

Note the word "margin" in the constraint description:

[image]

The problem with connecting to the margins is that you do not know what the margins will be when the app runs. It is a risky strategy. But you do know where the edges of the view will be, so if you want to match them, constrain to *them*, not to the margins. Use the margins only if you really want to match the margins, whatever they may be. For example, a constraint with a constant of 0 to a margin guarantees a nice space to the edge of the superview. But you do not want any space!

Comment: unfortunately no. just tried it with a UIView and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: sure https://github.com/eikebartels/iPadTest  https://github.com/eikebartels/iPadTest.git

Comment: ups. but now. Just pull. Thanks

Comment: Thanks heaps for that!! That solved my problem. Didn't know anything about the margin.