# Auto Layout Not So Auto

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I have the most basic set up possible. See pic 1:

[image: pic1]

Believe it or not this is my first project using AutoLayout, I have created everything prior programatically. This basic set up is literally a `UIWebView` with 1 custom `UIView` positioned at the bottom. Previously I was using a tool bar that handled everything for me and had no issues with constraints whatsoever. However, the tool bar created discrepancies for event handling when adding a `UILongPressGesture` to the subview of the `UIBarButtonItem` so I decided to convert the tool bar to a `UIView` (Even inserting a UIView into a tool bar, it naturally converts to a button item) for easier handling. But run-time, the view gets pushed off screen by half of the `UIView` size (48px) See Pic 2. Then when I add buttons, it just gets worse:

[image: pic2]

I have reviewed the documents and the support [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1) with no results. I've spent about 24 hours in total researching it and learned a lot, so my efforts aren't in vein. **I KNOW** by 'Adding Missing Constraints', the constraints are just recommendations based on the current set up, they aren't concrete in all cases, so I did try to create my own with control drag after reviewing the documents but my set up concluded with no different results, and exponentially more sloppy. So  I decided to include the populated constraints by Xcode below :

**UIWebView Constraints**

[image: pic3]

**Custom UIView (toolBar) Constraints**

[image: pic4]

Any solid starting point recommendations? Does Intrinsic Size have anything to do with it?

**EDIT : WORKING CONSTRAINTS** I didn't realize you could simply omit a constraint. It seems the culprit was adding one to the top layout guide.

[image: pic 5]

Just for answerer @Matt :

**Constant 0 result :** there are small gaps at edges

[image: pic6]

-16 for leading space/trailing space results as a true toolbar emulation in my case with no outstanding warnings or issues. Thanks

Comment: What's the question? I can't find the specific problem among all the talk here.

Comment: Hey @matt the question isn't a question. More of a statement. My auto layout constraints aren't working. I've added my own constraints as opposed to using 'Add Missing' but it still results with the UIView being pushed off screen.  Essentially asking, what do I need to do to make it not get pushed off screen or lose its frame

Comment: Well Stack Overflow is about questions, not statements. If you have a specific question, please do ask it. "Worse" is not a problem description. Say clearly what is happening, what you desire, and what you've tried. Give a little time and thought to structuring your question. This will make it much easier for you to obtain help (if you want help). Thanks!

Comment: @matt I guess the better question would be: How to make my UIView emulate a toolbar?

Comment: Could we talk about why you don't want an actual toolbar? :)

Comment: @matt yes Matt. That's why my question is dialogue intense. The reason I don't use one is in my question. I had a tool bar previously with no problems. Love it. But I need to add a UILongPressGesture to some buttons in the toolbar. As you know you, you can't add a gesture to a bar button item you have to add it to the buttons subview in it. That's no problem. I did that. It just wasn't reliable and the long press didn't get called sometimes. So to ensure it would I created a UIView the size of toolbar to emulate one so adding gestures to buttons would be more fluid

Comment: "As you know you, you can't add a gesture to a bar button item you have to add it to the buttons subview in it. That's no problem. I did that. It just wasn't reliable and the long press didn't get called sometimes" But I don't think making this a UIView is going to solve that. A button has its own internal gesture detection; that can conflict with a long press gesture recognizer. You're going to have to think about that conflict in any case.

Comment: Meanwhile, just to get this question closed off, I've given you a little lecture on auto layout as an answer.

Comment: @matt thanks for your patience. I was using `[[[self.toolBar subviews] objectAtIndex:[[self.toolBar items] indexOfObject:self.scrollDown]] addGestureRecognizer:quickScroll];` but sometimes it got called, and other times it didn't, so before even transitioning from the toolbar to a UIView I tested adding the additional gesture out on a normal button and it worked consistently in my favor

Comment: Okay, up to you. My answer still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's talk about the view at the bottom of your interface and how you would use auto layout to position and size it the way a toolbar would be positioned and sized.

To use auto layout, you need to supply sufficient info to determine both position and size. This view is a subview of the view controller's main view. The main view will be resized depending on the screen, so we want to use auto layout to resize the subview ("toolbar") as well. This is what auto layout is for!

So constrain subview leading edge to the leading edge of the superview, and constrain subview trailing edge to the trailing edge of the superview, both with a `constant` of 0. Now the right and left edges match the superview!

That takes care of horizontal position and size.

Now let's talk about vertical position. The position should be the bottom. So constrain subview bottom edge to the bottom layout guide of the view controller, again with a `constant` of 0. Now the bottom of the view is at the bottom!

The only thing we don't know is the top of the subview. This, in our situation, is the same as knowing its height. So give the subview a height constraint, set its `constant` to a reasonable value like 40, and you're done.

Comment: Your the best. You really, are. I fixed my constraints and all is in working order now. But please review my edited question, your knowledge is resourceful right now, I'm here to learn. Can you offer input on why setting the constraint to -16 like xCode provides works but constant 0 does not? When constant 0 makes more sense to me? BTW, the issue was I was adding a top layout constraint, that was causing it to push down, I didn't realize you could omit one, I thought all 4 were used in tandem.  After omitting it based on your recommendation it's a charmer!

Comment: You got messed up by margins. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27976007/341994